# How to display task assigned to field in document library view?

Tags: workflow, document-library, column, tasks

When you assign a workflow to a document or item, under the task that gets created, you can see who the task is assigned to based on where you are within the workflow.  My goal is to create a generic "Assigned To" column within a document library and pull the "Assigned To" value from task and display it.  Can anyone help describe how to accomplish this?  Thanks...

Comment: Are you using designer workflow or visual studio workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Loopup column. 
check the below video how to create lookup column and apply it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziVngsLQ94w

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are looking to have a custom column that pulls data from the existing Assigned To column from task list for a workflow. So ideally this new column in the document library should contain the name of whoever the current workflow task is assigned to. But based on the lookup video I just saw, there is no option to pull data from existing columns in a task library. Are we missing something here? -Nick's teammate

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be you can update that "Assigned To" column from workflow itself.
Read the Assigned to variable in Workflow and update that to "Assigned To" column.